# Create a secondary index using java in Aerospike

Tags: java, indexing, aerospike

I am new to Aerospike DB and I need to know how can I create namespaces as well as secondary indexes using java code.

Sample record -

```
    { student ID: 121,
    class : 10,
    lastAttendedDate:1475742032000,
    first_name:ABC,
    middle_name:xyz,
    last_name:pqr,
    days_present:213
    }
```

I want to create index on three bins (student Id, class and lastAttendedDate) in my test application. How can I achieve this using java.?

Thanks and regards,

Vibhav

Comment: IndexTask task = client.createIndex(null, "foo", "bar", 
    "idx_foo_bar_baz", "baz", IndexType.NUMERIC);
You can change index type.

http://www.aerospike.com/docs/client/java/usage/query/sindex.html

Comment: @cody123 : this is a single field index. i need an index on three bins. like compund indexes.

Comment: @VibhavSinghRohilla, Aerospike does not support compound indexes (index on multiple bins).

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, Aerospike does not support indexes on multiple bins.